Patch Antenna lower Gain with bigger ground
I am designing a circular patch antenna. The design seems good, achieving <-25 dB S11 and 9dB gain. I am trying to reach even higher gain. For different reasons I need to extend the ground from 10x10 cm to 40x40 cm, leaving the antenna in one of the edges (I can not center it because I'll place more antennas, not an array, just other bands). I don't know why when I extend the ground, the directivity decreases to 8.5 or 8.3 dB. The feeding technique used is coaxial backfeed at 0.9*Patch_Radius. Maybe that is the problem? S11 is still good...
The RFCAD used is CST.

